# Making phpmyadmin accessible over internet

Tags: windows, mysql, port-forwarding, xampp, phpmyadmin

I have XAMPP installed on my Windows XP server.

I have port 3306 (mysql) and 80 (apache) on the machine forwarded to 5016 and 5011 on the router respectively.

I am able to access the phpmyadmin page from the local network using `http://10.0.1.200/phpmyadmin` , as i have granted access to all ip's in the configuration files. (It asks me for a username upon loading as i set authentication to 'cookie').

I have also created a user with a '%' Host with privileges. However when I try to access it using `http://<publicip>:5016/phpmyadmin` i get the following text (spaces are actually symbols):

```
J   
5.5.36    ydh^}zn; ÿ÷ €          wh"o,)(.Lu)g mysql_native_password !  ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

Do i need to configure something else maybe? Or am i just using a wrong url?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to **phpMyAdmin** from outside your LAN, you have to forward port 80 only (HTTP). So you will have access to `http://<public IP>:5011/phpmyadmin`

I assume you forwarded 5011 -> 80 and 5016 -> 3360. So you have to remove the second one. The strange symbols you are getting now is the MySQL response. **phpMyAdmin** connects itself to MySQL via local socket. So you don't need to open (nor forward) **MySQL** port (3306)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. For security reason I wouldn't open MySQL port (3306) even for LAN. Unless you need to access MySQL from another machine, the best is to keep the port closed on the server itself.